# Best Practice for "fastcgi_pass" Directive Location in NGiNX

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, best-practices

Is best to put the `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000` directive in the `fastcgi_params` file for **NGiNX**, or to explicitly state it in the location for `\.php$`?

Or does it not really matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to put it directly in the `location` block, because the `fastcgi_params` file is intended to be shared by multiple blocks which can pass to a different FastCGI server. The `fastcgi_params` also gets rid of the "noise" of all the paramater definitions which are not important most of the time, but the `fastcgi_pass` directive is always important when dealing with configurations. Lastly, the name `fastcgi_params` implies that it only contains `fastcgi_param` directives -- using it for other directives will confuse others (and probably you in a couple months) trying to understand the configuration.

Comment: Good points. I was curious, because I felt the same way about the confusion part. [In their full example](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample) they have a `fastcgi_index` directive listed in their `fastcgi_conf` file, which I found rather odd. However, it is named `fastcgi_conf`, rather than `fastcgi_params`, which makes slightly more sense.